# We need to find the average of the column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, average, nan

```
         time1         x     y        z         GMT- 5             key     time2        a          b          c           GMT                   cut_off   time_diff new_column
1   1.674841e+09    -1.10   64.11   -1.33   2023-01-27 12:43:22 PM  0   1.674841e+09    2.96    606.270614  2.80    2023-01-27 12:43:24 PM  1.674841e+09    2.308100    NaN
2   1.674841e+09    -1.10   64.11   -1.33   2023-01-27 12:43:22 PM  0   1.674841e+09    2.96    584.696883  2.80    2023-01-27 12:43:26 PM  1.674841e+09    4.303636    NaN
3   1.674841e+09    -1.10   64.11   -1.33   2023-01-27 12:43:22 PM  0   1.674841e+09    2.96    615.295633  2.80    2023-01-27 12:43:28 PM  1.674841e+09    6.298568    NaN
4   1.674841e+09    -1.10   64.11   -1.33   2023-01-27 12:43:22 PM  0   1.674841e+09    2.96    587.050575  2.80    2023-01-27 12:43:30 PM  1.674841e+09    8.293623    NaN
5   1.674841e+09    -2.24   93.51   -2.36   2023-01-27 12:43:46 PM  0   1.674841e+09    2.96    584.700016  2.80    2023-01-27 12:43:46 PM  1.674841e+09    0.007554    0.007554
100 1.674842e+09    -1.24   84.73   -2.44   2023-01-27 12:49:07 PM  0   1.674843e+09    2.30    1024.363758 2.64    2023-01-27 01:13:11 PM  1.674843e+09    1444.068500 NaN
101 1.674842e+09    -1.24   84.73   -2.44   2023-01-27 12:49:07 PM  0   1.674843e+09    2.31    1011.438119 2.64    2023-01-27 01:13:13 PM  1.674843e+09    1446.063470 NaN
102 1.674842e+09    -1.24   84.73   -2.44   2023-01-27 12:49:07 PM  0   1.674843e+09    2.32    1005.181835 2.64    2023-01-27 01:13:15 PM  1.674843e+09    1448.058710 NaN
103 1.674842e+09    -1.24   84.73   -2.44   2023-01-27 12:49:07 PM  0   1.674843e+09    2.34    989.515657  2.64    2023-01-27 01:13:17 PM  1.674843e+09    1450.053643 NaN
104 1.674842e+09    -1.24   84.73   -2.44   2023-01-27 12:49:07 PM  0   1.674843e+09    2.34    1016.183097 2.64    2023-01-27 01:13:19 PM  1.674843e+09    1452.048679 NaN
105 1.674842e+09    -1.57   80.04   -1.96   2023-01-27 12:49:06 PM  0   1.674842e+09    2.02    1652.185708 2.88    2023-01-27 12:49:06 PM  1.674842e+09    0.001867    0.001867
```

We actually need the row without nan value in column: 'new_column". here it is the rows: 5 and 105
Bu we need the average of 'x', 'y', 'z'  of the (rows 1 to 5) and (rows 100 to 105)  in the 5th row and 105th row

The desired output:

```
          time1            x     y        z         GMT- 5             key     time2        a          b          c           GMT                   cut_off   time_diff new_column
    5   1.674841e+09    -1.328   69.99   -1.536   2023-01-27 12:43:46 PM  0   1.674841e+09    2.96    584.700016  2.80    2023-01-27 12:43:46 PM  1.674841e+09    0.007554    0.007554
    105 1.674842e+09    -1.295   69.82   -2.36  2023-01-27 12:49:06 PM  0   1.674842e+09    2.02    1652.185708 2.88    2023-01-27 12:49:06 PM  1.674842e+09    0.001867    0.001867
```

​

Comment: for each instance in the dataframe you want the average of x, y, and z? Or just in instances 1:5 and 100:105?

Comment: for each instance. we have more rows in between 5 and 100 with column "new_column" has nan values and values

Comment: Do you want it for the average of the five instance which come before?

Comment: here it is the row 1 to 5 and 100 to 105. because the value in the 'new_column' are nan for 1 to 4 and 100 to 104. it depends on the nan values in 'new_column'. it can be 5 instance, it can be 10 etc

Comment: output:
5   1.674841e+09    -2.24   93.51   -2.36   2023-01-27 12:43:46 PM  0   1.674841e+09    2.96    584.700016  2.80    2023-01-27 12:43:46 PM  1.674841e+09    0.007554    0.007554
in this row, the 'x' value will be average of the values in the column 1 to 5 and for y and z respectievely

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the table above and put a red box around what values need to be averaged?

Comment: Please see my desired output.

Comment: I can't add screenshots. the averege of the row: 1 to 5 and 100 to 105 of the column 'x', 'y' and 'z'

Comment: Done. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets try and create a group. We can use cumulative sum to do this on the "new column". Just replace the Nan values with 0 and the others with 1 and shift it down by 1

```
df["binary"] = df["new_column"].fillna(0)
df.loc[df.binary!=0,"binary"] = 1
df["binary"] = df["binary"].shift(1,fill_value=0)
df["cumsum"] = df["binary"].cumsum()
```

```
           time1     x      y     z  ...    time_diff new_column binary  cumsum
0   1.670000e+09 -1.10  64.11 -1.33  ...     2.308100        NaN    0.0     0.0
1   1.670000e+09 -1.10  64.11 -1.33  ...     4.303636        NaN    0.0     0.0
2   1.670000e+09 -1.10  64.11 -1.33  ...     6.298568        NaN    0.0     0.0
3   1.670000e+09 -1.10  64.11 -1.33  ...     8.293623        NaN    0.0     0.0
4   1.670000e+09 -2.24  93.51 -2.36  ...     0.007554   0.007554    0.0     0.0
5   1.670000e+09 -1.24  84.73 -2.44  ...  1444.068500        NaN    1.0     1.0
6   1.670000e+09 -1.24  84.73 -2.44  ...  1446.063470        NaN    0.0     1.0
7   1.670000e+09 -1.24  84.73 -2.44  ...  1448.058710        NaN    0.0     1.0
8   1.670000e+09 -1.24  84.73 -2.44  ...  1450.053643        NaN    0.0     1.0
9   1.670000e+09 -1.24  84.73 -2.44  ...  1452.048679        NaN    0.0     1.0
10  1.670000e+09 -1.57  80.04 -1.96  ...     0.001867   0.001867    0.0     1.0
```

After this it is a simple groupby on the cumulative sum

```
G = df.groupby("cumsum")
df["x_avg"] = G['x'].transform('mean')
df["y_avg"] = G['y'].transform('mean')
df["z_avg"] = G['z'].transform('mean')

filtered_df = df[~pd.isna(df["new_column"])]
```

```
           time1     x      y     z  ... cumsum  x_avg      y_avg  z_avg
4   1.670000e+09 -2.24  93.51 -2.36  ...    0.0 -1.328  69.990000 -1.536
10  1.670000e+09 -1.57  80.04 -1.96  ...    1.0 -1.295  83.948333 -2.360
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be this.

```
df['new_column'] = df[['x', 'y', 'z']].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: We only have 2 rows in the output here, but this code shows more rows.

Comment: It shows every row.